# How to calculate the percentile?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, percentile

I have access logs such as below stored in a mongodb instance:

```
Time                           Service                      Latency
[27/08/2013:11:19:22 +0000]    "POST Service A HTTP/1.1"    403
[27/08/2013:11:19:24 +0000]    "POST Service B HTTP/1.1"    1022 
[27/08/2013:11:22:10 +0000]    "POST Service A HTTP/1.1"    455
```

Is there an analytics function like `PERCENTILE_DISC` in Oracle to calculate the percentile?

I would like to calculate latency percentiles over a period of time.

Answer (score 10):

There still appears to be no native way to calculate percentiles but by combining a few aggregate operators you can get the same result.

```
db.items.aggregate([
        {'$group': {
            '_id': {
                'league': '$league',
                'base': '$base',
                'type': '$type'
            },
            'value': {'$push': '$chaosequiv'}
        }},
        {'$unwind': '$value'},
        {'$sort': {'value': 1}},
        {'$group': {'_id': '$_id', 'value': {'$push': '$value'}}},
        {'$project': {
            '_id': 1,
            'value': {'$arrayElemAt': ['$value', {'$floor': {'$multiply': [0.25, {'$size': '$value'}]}}]}
        }}
    ], allowDiskUse=True)
```

Note I wrote my original code in pymongo for a problem that needed to group on 3 fields in the first group so this may be more complex than necessary for a single field.  I would write a solution specific to this question but I don't think there is enough specific information.

Comment: I know code for a Path of Exile trading tool, when I see it. :)

Comment: does sorting first and then grouping not work ? rather than grouping, unwinding, sorting, grouping again.

Answer (score 4):

Starting `Mongo 4.4`, the `$group` stage has a new aggregation operator [`$accumulator`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/accumulator/#accumulator-aggregation) allowing custom accumulations of documents as they get grouped, via javascript user defined functions.

Thus, in order to find the 20th percentile:

```
// { "a" : 25, "b" : 12 }
// { "a" : 89, "b" : 73 }
// { "a" : 25, "b" : 7  }
// { "a" : 25, "b" : 17 }
// { "a" : 89, "b" : 14 }
// { "a" : 89, "b" : 17 }
// { "a" : 25, "b" : 24 }
// { "a" : 25, "b" : 15 }
// { "a" : 25, "b" : 22 }
// { "a" : 25, "b" : 94 }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: {
    _id: "$a",
    percentile: {
      $accumulator: {
        accumulateArgs: ["$b"],
        init: function() { return []; },
        accumulate: function(bs, b) { return bs.concat(b); },
        merge: function(bs1, bs2) { return bs1.concat(bs2); },
        finalize: function(bs) {
          bs.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b });
          return bs[Math.floor(bs.length*.2) + 1];
        },
        lang: "js"
      }
    }
  }}
])
// { "_id" : 89, "percentile" : 17 }
// { "_id" : 25, "percentile" : 15 }
```

The accumulator:

- accumulates on the field `b` (`accumulateArgs`)
- is initialised to an empty array (`init`)
- accumulates `b` items in an array (`accumulate` and `merge`)
- and finally performs the percentile calculation on `b` items (`finalize`)

Answer (score 0):

Calculating percentile from 0 to 100 (step 5)

```
// { "session": 1, "date" : 2013-08-27 11:00::00, "latency" : 403 }
// { "session": 1, "date" : 2013-08-27 11:00::01, "latency" : 1022 }
// { "session": 1, "date" : 2013-08-27 11:00::02, "latency" : 455 }
// { "session": 1, "date" : 2013-08-27 11:00::02, "latency" : 307 }
// { "session": 2, "date" : 2013-08-27 12:00::00, "latency" : 403 }
// { "session": 2, "date" : 2013-08-27 12:00::01, "latency" : 1022 }
// { "session": 2, "date" : 2013-08-27 12:00::02, "latency" : 455 }
// { "session": 2, "date" : 2013-08-27 12:00::02, "latency" : 307 }

var interval = 5

db.getCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $group:{
            _id: { $toString: "$session" },
            value: { $push: "$atency" }
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields:{
            index : {$range: [0, 100, interval]}
        }
    },
    {$unwind: "$index"},
    {
        $addFields:{
            p_index : {$divide: ["$index", 100]}
        }
    },
    {
        $addFields:{
            percentile_x : {$toDouble: {'$arrayElemAt': ['$value', {'$floor': {'$multiply': ["$p_index", {'$size': '$value'}]}}]}}
        }
    },
    {   $project: {
           'percentile': "$index",
           'value': "$percentile_x"
        }
    },
        {$sort: {
          percentile: 1
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering there is still no native way to do this, I'll be using an:

- `$aggregate` as well with a `$push` to keep track of all the values.
- Then I'll just use `np.percentile(values, xth_percentile)` to get the xth percentile. e.g. `np.percentile([0,1,10,30,100], 25)` to get the 25th percentile of that array.

For reference, there have been for many, many years a [JIRA card](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7463) and an open [pull request](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/pull/1310) for this feature. Go show your support.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest MongoDB 7.0+, you can use the [$percentile](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/percentile/#examples) to compute the percentile for data.

You might be able to achieve a similar behaviour as `PERCENTILE_DISC` you mentioned with below syntax:

```js
{
    $setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: {
        latency: 1,
      },
      output: {
        latencyPercentile: {
          $percentile: {
            input: "$latency",
            p: [0.05, 0.5, 0.95],
            method: "approximate",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }
```