# MongoDB: calculate 90th percentile among all documents

Tags: mongodb

I need to calculate the 90th percentile of the duration where the duration for each document is defined as `finish_time - start_time`.

My plan was to:

1. Create `$project` to calculate that duration in seconds for each document.
2. Calculate the index  (in sorted documents list) that correspond to the 90th percentile: `90th_percentile_index = 0.9 * amount_of_documents`.
3. Sort the documents by the `$duration` variable the was created.
4. Use the `90th_percentile_index` to `$limit` the documents.
5. Choose the first document out of the limited subset of document.

I'm new to `MongoDB` so I  guess the query can be improved. So, the query looks like:

```
db.getCollection('scans').aggregate([
{ 
  $project: {
    duration: {
      $divide: [{$subtract: ["$finish_time", "$start_time"]}, 1000] // duration is in seconds
    },
    Percentile90Index: {
      $multiply: [0.9, "$total_number_of_documents"] // I don't know how to get the total number of documents.. 
    }
}
},
{
    $sort : {"$duration": 1},
},
{
    $limit: "$Percentile90Index"
},
{
    $group: {
    _id: "_id",
    percentiles90 : { $max: "$duration" } // selecting the max, i.e, first document after the limit , should give the result.
  }
}
])
```

The problem I have is that I don't know how to get the `total_number_of_documents` and therefore I can't calculate the index.

Example:
let's say I have only 3 documents:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1"),
    "start_time" : ISODate("2019-02-03T12:00:00.000Z"),
    "finish_time" : ISODate("2019-02-03T12:01:00.000Z"),
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("2"),
    "start_time" : ISODate("2019-02-03T12:00:00.000Z"),
    "finish_time" : ISODate("2019-02-03T12:03:00.000Z"),

}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("3"),
    "start_time" : ISODate("2019-02-03T12:00:00.000Z"),
    "finish_time" : ISODate("2019-02-03T12:08:00.000Z"),
}
```

So I would expect the result to be something like:

```
{
percentiles50 : 3 // in minutes, since percentiles50=3 is the minimum value that setisfies the request of atleast 50% of the documents have duration <= percentiles50
}
```

I used percentiles 50th in the example because I only gave 3 documents but it really doesn't matter, just show me please a query for the i-th percentiles and it will be fine :-)

Comment: Can you add a sample data and an expected result?

Comment: @Neodan I've edited my post with examples documents and desired output. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the percentile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18484571/how-to-calculate-the-percentile)